# Failed: Template parse errors: Angular 2

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, testing

I'm getting the following error once running Unit-test angular CLI. The following error is on a form.

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("<form [ERROR ->]#userForm = "ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm.value)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="e")
```

The html form

```
<form #userForm = "ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm.value)">
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputCountry">Country</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="country" placeholder="Country" ng name="country" ngModel>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  [...]
  ],
  imports: [
  FormsModule,
  [...] 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You should import `FormsModule` to your testing module

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...,
  imports: [
     FormsModule,
  ],
})
```